# Solution For Side By Side Bar Graph Error: can only have an x or y aesthetic

Tags: r, layout, bar-chart

I was having trouble making a side-by-side bar graph with a column containing characters (ride_month), a column containing the total numeric data (ride_duration) for rider two types(member_casual).

```
ggplot(data=bike_data_v4)+
+   geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=ride_month,fill=member_casual))+
+   geom_col(position = "dodge")

Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`:
! geom_col requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

my dataset originally looked like this:
[image]

To fix my problem, I made a new dataset grouping member_casual and ride_month. Next, I piped a sum of ride_duration.

```
bike_data_removedcols_V2 <- bike_data_removedcols %>% 
  group_by(member_casual, ride_month) %>%
  summarise(ride_duration_sum=sum(ride_duration))
```

I took the newly created dataset and applied it to this ggplot function:

```
ggplot(data = bike_data_removedcols_V2, aes(ride_month, ride_duration_sum, fill=member_casual, group = member_casual))+
      geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

Success!
[image]

Comment: That was a random image I found on Google. Just going for a side-by-side

Comment: quite a way to use this platform for new people getting into tech :) (also yes, I did do that)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Example of a search: (17 hits) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+barplot+ggplot2+side-by-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a grouped bar chart then add `group` aesthetics like this:

```
  ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(ride_month, ride_duration, fill=member_casual, group = member_casual))+
    geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

Here is an example with `mtcars` dataset:

```
  ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg, fill=am, group = am))+
    geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think all the variations I tried weren't working because I was missing the "group =" syntax

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
library(ggplot2)
data = mtcars

ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(carb), y = mpg, fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```